# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, android-intent, google-play-services

I am having  two issues. I am trying Google map API with Google Play services.I need your help.Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

My manifest file is:

```
`enter code here`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.map"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB5Ig0vlCPeGIZgxj6nyY3XHHpxZJcDfb8"/>

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
    />

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" 
    />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:839)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-23 21:35:49.848: E/AndroidRuntime(6538):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please give me a solution to resolve this issue

Comment: You should post your manifest.

Comment: Hey take a look at his it may help [chick here][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614561/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-sp/%22here%20is%20the%20link%22]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Play Store is not on your device, and so the `market://` `Uri` is not resolving.

Comment: @mikatoarido: Buy a device that has the Play Store on it. The Play Services Framework will not be on your device either, and so Maps V2 will not work. Or, switch to a different mapping engine, like OpenStreetMap, that can be run on any device.