# How can i add all of the prod obtained?

Tags: java, android

this is my logcat

```
02-14 01:53:19.385: I/ActivityManager(286): START u0 {cmp=com.example.midterm2ndsem/.Order} from pid 1901
02-14 01:53:19.395: W/WindowManager(286): Failure taking screenshot for (343x201) to layer 21010
02-14 01:53:19.415: I/ActivityManager(286): START u0 {act=com.example.midterm2ndsem} from pid 1901
02-14 01:53:19.435: W/System.err(1901): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.midterm2ndsem }
02-14 01:53:19.435: W/System.err(1901):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
02-14 01:53:19.435: W/System.err(1901):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
02-14 01:53:19.445: W/System.err(1901):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)
02-14 01:53:19.445: W/System.err(1901):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3331)
02-14 01:53:19.445: W/System.err(1901):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3566)
02-14 01:53:19.445: W/System.err(1901):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3534)
02-14 01:53:19.445: W/System.err(1901):     at com.example.midterm2ndsem.Home1$1.onClick(Home1.java:59)
02-14 01:53:19.455: W/System.err(1901):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-14 01:53:19.455: W/System.err(1901):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-14 01:53:19.465: W/System.err(1901):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-14 01:53:19.465: W/System.err(1901):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-14 01:53:19.465: W/System.err(1901):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-14 01:53:19.475: W/System.err(1901):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-14 01:53:19.475: W/System.err(1901):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 01:53:19.475: W/System.err(1901):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-14 01:53:19.485: W/System.err(1901):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-14 01:53:19.485: W/System.err(1901):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-14 01:53:19.485: W/System.err(1901):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 01:53:20.016: E/SurfaceFlinger(36): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
02-14 01:53:21.735: I/Choreographer(1901): Skipped 280 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-14 01:53:23.885: D/dalvikvm(1901): GC_CONCURRENT freed 191K, 10% free 2839K/3144K, paused 12ms+158ms, total 547ms
02-14 01:53:24.055: I/Choreographer(1901): Skipped 94 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-14 01:53:25.725: D/dalvikvm(286): GC_CONCURRENT freed 750K, 16% free 6183K/7276K, paused 14ms+52ms, total 1141ms
02-14 01:53:29.565: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1901): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
02-14 01:53:29.565: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1901):   in android.widget.EditText{40d55bd8 VFED..CL .F....I. 487,103-537,143 #7f080001 app:id/qtytide}
02-14 01:53:29.565: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1901):   0: sent at 5427887000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=5427887, downTime=5427758, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
02-14 01:53:31.465: D/dalvikvm(487): GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 71% free 4009K/13652K, paused 7ms+35ms, total 522msandroid.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:53:58.225: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594): null
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d274b0 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:53:58.235: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:53:58.235: W/ActivityManager(286): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@410495b8
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d4fb18 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d4fb18 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:53:58.257: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594): null
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d4fb18 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:53:58.276: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:53:58.285: W/ActivityManager(286): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@41049d30
nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:43.105: D/ExchangeService(594): Received deviceId from Email app: null
02-14 01:54:43.105: D/ExchangeService(594): !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
02-14 01:54:48.195: D/ExchangeService(594): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onCreate
02-14 01:54:48.215: W/Trace(594): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.215: W/Trace(594): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.225: D/ExchangeService(594): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
02-14 01:54:48.225: W/Trace(594): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.245: W/ActivityManager(286): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-14 01:54:48.255: W/Trace(594): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.255: D/ExchangeService(594): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false
02-14 01:54:48.255: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.265: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.325: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.325: W/Trace(1926): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.357: D/ExchangeService(594): !!! Email application not found; stopping self
02-14 01:54:48.375: W/Trace(594): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.375: W/Trace(594): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.395: W/ActivityManager(286): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
02-14 01:54:48.405: W/Trace(594): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce6300 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce6300 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:54:48.415: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594): null
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce6300 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:54:48.527: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:54:48.527: W/ActivityManager(286): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fc6168
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd0358 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd0358 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:54:48.546: E/ActivityThread(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594): null
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd0358 that was originally bound here
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
02-14 01:54:48.595: E/StrictMode(594):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-14 01:54:48.595: W/ActivityManager(286): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@40fc56d8
02-14 01:54:48.695: D/dalvikvm(594): GC_CONCURRENT freed 476K, 20% free 2472K/3068K, paused 75ms+79ms, total 265ms
```

code:

```
public class Order extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText qtymilk;
    EditText qtytide;
    EditText qtypaper;
    EditText qtycheese;
    EditText qtypotato;
    TextView milk;
    TextView tide;
    TextView paper;
    TextView cheese;
    TextView potato;
    TextView totalmilk;
    TextView totaltide;
    TextView totalpaper;
    TextView totalcheese;
    TextView totalpotato;
    EditText discount1;


    double num1, num2, prod1;
    double num3, num4, prod2;
    double num5, num6, prod3;
    double num7, num8, prod4;
    double num9, num10, prod5;

    double grandt = prod1 + prod2 + prod3 + prod4 + prod5;


    TextView grandtotal;

    Button total;
    Button summary;
    Button discount;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

        milk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        tide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        paper = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        cheese = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        potato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

        qtymilk = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtymilk);
        qtytide = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtytide);
        qtypaper = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtypaper);
        qtycheese = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtycheese);
        qtypotato = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.qtypotato);


        totalmilk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalmilk);
        totaltide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totaltide);
        totalpaper = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalpaper);
        totalcheese = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalcheese);
        totalpotato = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalpotato1);

        total = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        total.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        discount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        discount.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        summary = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        summary.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.order, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(qtymilk.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(milk.getText().toString());
            prod1 = num1 * num2;
            totalmilk.setText(Double.toString(prod1));

            num3 = Double.parseDouble(qtytide.getText().toString());
            num4 = Double.parseDouble(tide.getText().toString());
            prod2 = num3 * num4;
            totaltide.setText(Double.toString(prod2));


            num5 = Double.parseDouble(qtypaper.getText().toString());
            num6 = Double.parseDouble(paper.getText().toString());
            prod3 = num5 * num6;
            totalpaper.setText(Double.toString(prod3));


            num7 = Double.parseDouble(qtycheese.getText().toString());
            num8 = Double.parseDouble(cheese.getText().toString());
            prod4 = num7 * num8;
            totalcheese.setText(Double.toString(prod4));

            num9 = Double.parseDouble(qtypotato.getText().toString());
            num10 = Double.parseDouble(potato.getText().toString());
            prod5 = num9 * num10;
            totalpotato.setText(Double.toString(prod5));


            grandtotal.setText(Double.toString(grand4));


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please tidy up your code..Its really difficult for us to find out the errors from such a post..

Comment: double num1,num2,prod1;
double num3,num4,prod2;
double num5,num6,prod3;
double num7,num8,prod4;
double num9,num10,prod5;

double grandt = prod1 + prod2 + prod3 + prod4 + prod5 ;


TextView grandtotal;

Comment: can you just tell me how to add three numbers in my textView

Comment: basically i have 3 textviews, with different values each, how can i add them using a single button

Comment: When you have several variables whose names differ only by a numerical suffix, you should probably use an array or a List instead.

Comment: 1. Check the logcat in the "Android Monitor" window in Android Studio. This will show you if there was an error while your program was running. 2. Use the debugger in Android Studio to step through your code to find out where the problem occurs. These are both important tools to learn as an Android programmer.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the string that you are parsing is not a double value. I bet that is your problem seeing as you are constantly using that

Comment: Your error and your code don't line up. There are no Intent objects there... Anyways, this is your error  and how to fix it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614561/android-content-activitynotfoundexception-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-sp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly consider breaking up your logic into smaller, readable methods. You also don't need to store the numbers as fields.

I.e. Remove this whole block of code...

```
double num1, num2, prod1;
double num3, num4, prod2;
double num5, num6, prod3;
double num7, num8, prod4;
double num9, num10, prod5;

double grandt = prod1 + prod2 + prod3 + prod4 + prod5;
```

---

Also, `Double.parseDouble` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the string that you are parsing is not a double value, so if your app is crashing for that reason, make sure those values are acually  numbers.

---

Here is a small sample of what it looks like you are trying  to achieve

```
private double getTotalMilk() {
    double quantity = Double.parseDouble(qtymilk.getText().toString());
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(milk.getText().toString());
    return quantity * amount;
}

private double getTotalTide() {
    double quantity = Double.parseDouble(qtytide.getText().toString());
    double amount = Double.parseDouble(tide.getText().toString());
    return quantity * amount;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
        double grandTotal = 0;

        double totalMilk = getTotalMilk();
        grandTotal += totalMilk;
        totalmilk.setText(Double.toString(totalMilk));

        double totalTide = getTotalTide();
        grandTotal += totalTide;
        totaltide.setText(Double.toString(totalTide));

        // Repeat pattern....

        grandtotal.setText(Double.toString(grandTotal));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can show your thanks by clicking the checkmark next to the answer :)

Comment: Still gets an error when adding the grandtotal

Comment: It shouldn't, as I said, parsing the numbers will crash the app if you are typing anything other than numbers in the textboxes

Comment: Either that or you have a NullPointerException on one of your views. Regardless, you should be including the crash logs in your questions

Comment: but i didnt type any letters in the textboxes you want to see my codes?

Comment: No, I want to see the logcat

Comment: how can i implement the logcat?

Comment: It's not something you implement. It is the crash logs for your app. It is extremely useful, and I suggest you find it. If you are using Intellij or Android Studio, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16817566/restore-logcat-window-within-android-studio

Comment: theres to many of them in my logcat window, which one should i pick?

Comment: Pick all of it if you have to, mostly whatever has the word "exception". Like NullPointerException or NumberFormatException. And please do not post it as an answer. Use the edit link under your question

Answer (score 0):

Remove your code line
  **double grandt = prod1 + prod2 + prod3 + prod4 + prod5;**
you can just use one global variable (only if you need that too). ie, 
double grandt;

rest you can do in onClick of button that

```
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            num1 = Double.parseDouble(qtymilk.getText().toString());
            num2 = Double.parseDouble(milk.getText().toString());
            double prod1 = num1 * num2; // <--------------
            totalmilk.setText(Double.toString(prod1));

            num3 = Double.parseDouble(qtytide.getText().toString());
            num4 = Double.parseDouble(tide.getText().toString());
            double prod2 = num3 * num4; 
            totaltide.setText(Double.toString(prod2));


            num5 = Double.parseDouble(qtypaper.getText().toString());
            num6 = Double.parseDouble(paper.getText().toString());
            double prod3 = num5 * num6; // <---------------------
            totalpaper.setText(Double.toString(prod3));


            num7 = Double.parseDouble(qtycheese.getText().toString());
            num8 = Double.parseDouble(cheese.getText().toString());
            double prod4 = num7 * num8;
            totalcheese.setText(Double.toString(prod4));

            num9 = Double.parseDouble(qtypotato.getText().toString());
            num10 = Double.parseDouble(potato.getText().toString());
            double prod5 = num9 * num10; <---------------
            totalpotato.setText(Double.toString(prod5));

            double grndttl = prod1+prod2; // or whatever you want.
```

Comment: sir i cant understand, where should i add all of my prod's? and where should i declare it?

Comment: Hey buddy can you put logcat errors generated by Android Studio? What actually causing you problem? Is it in parsing text to Double? or somewhere else? Put your logs here. And by the way what is grand4 in 
            grandtotal.setText(Double.toString(grand4)); where did you declared it?

Comment: grand4 is my error it should be grandt

Comment: i dont know how to use logcat, is there something wrong wth 
double grandt = prod1+ prod2+prod3+prod4+prod5;
???

Comment: Hey, have you solved your problem??If not I am gussing you forget to mention your activity in manifest file. If this is the case , first include all your activities to manifest.xml of your android application.